# Storing items from a foreach loop in an array, then accessing them

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, foreach

I'm getting some string values via a foreach loop and trying to store them into a List, but apparently it's not working/storing.

Here's the code:

```
private List<string> fbPictures;

void getParseResults()
    {
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("IdealStunts").OrderBy("time").Limit(10);
        query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = t.Result;
            Debug.LogError("RESULTS: " + results.ToString());
            foreach (var obj in results)
            {
                var fbID = obj.Get<string>("fbid");
                fbPictures.Add(fbID);
                }
            });
    }
```

If I try to print out in the console the values, it works. But adding them to the list doesn't. I really can't figure this out.

Also, can I access individual items from the list? Say I want the third item. Do I do **fbPictures[1]** (for the second item)?

Comment: Don't ever just say "it doesn't work". Say what about it doesn't work. I'm guessing you got an exception? Include the exception details in your question.

Comment: Is your List<string> fbPictures already initialized?

Comment: You were right, embee, it wasn't. Also, thank you for your hemp, mason. Sorry for being dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize the fbPictures object. You need to do that prior to adding anything to it. Change

```
private List<string> fbPictures;
```

to

```
private List<string> fbPictures=new List<string>();
```

You can access individual items from the list with this syntax...

```
fbPictures[0] //first object
fbPictures[1] // second object
```

Remember, indexes in most programming languages start with 0, so the index of the last item will always be one less than fbPictures.Count. Also, don't try to access an object unless you're sure it's there. That's a quick ticket to a NullReferenceException.

Comment: It works perfectly! I see that it wasn't properly initialized. Thank you.